# Python: how to use the value stored in a variable?

Tags: python, jira

Here's the code snippet:

```
# Get details from the user.
jira_url = str(raw_input("JIRA URL: "))            # https://jira.mydomain.com
jira_prj = str(raw_input("JIRA Project: "))        # MYPROJ
jira_uid = str(raw_input("JIRA ID: "))             # admin
jira_pas = str(getpass.getpass("JIRA Password: ")) # p@s$wOrd!

# JIRA stuff.
jira = JIRA(server=jira_url, basic_auth=(jira_uid, jira_pas))
search_alert_issues = jira.search_issues("project = %s AND issuetype = Alert AND status = Submitted AND reporter in (anonymous)") % jira_prj
search_alert_issues
```

Objectives:

1. Connect to JIRA server.
2. Run the `search_alert_issues`.

Expectation:

```
>>> jira = JIRA(server='https://jira.mydomain.com', basic_auth=('admin', 'p@s$wOrd!'))
>>> search_alert_issues = jira.search_issues("project = MYPROJ AND issuetype = Alert AND status = Submitted AND reporter in (anonymous)")
>>> search_alert_issues
[<JIRA Issue: key=u'MYPROJ-35460', id=u'129419'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'MYPROJ-35459', id=u'129418'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'MYPROJ-35458', id=u'129417'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'MYPROJ-35457', id=u'129416'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'MYPROJ-35456', id=u'129415'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'MYPROJ-35455', id=u'129414'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'MYPROJ-35454', id=u'129413'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'MYPROJ-35453', id=u'129412'>, <JIRA Issue:     key=u'MYPROJ-35452', id=u'129411'>, <JIRA Issue: key=u'MYPROJ-35451', id=u'129410'>]
>>>
```

Reality:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ajat.py", line 82, in <module>
search_alert_issues = jira.search_issues("project = %s AND issuetype = Alert AND status = Submitted AND     reporter in (anonymous)") % jira_prj
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 1587, in search_issues
    resource = self._get_json('search', params=search_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 2033, in _get_json
    r = self._session.get(url, params=params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 78, in get
    return self.__verb('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 74, in __verb
    raise_on_error(r, verb=verb, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/utils.py", line 120, in raise_on_error
    r.status_code, error, r.url, request=request, response=r, **kwargs)
jira.utils.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400
    text: Error in the JQL Query: The character '%' is a reserved JQL character. You must enclose it in a     string or use the escape '\u0025' instead. (line 1, character 11)
```

Questions:

1. `search_alert_issues` should be able to use the value stored in `jira_prj` variable, right?
2. But why it isn't working? All jira_* variables are showing their values when I did a simple print command on them.
3. How am I going to use the value stored in `jira_prj`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
search_alert_issues = jira.search_issues("project = %s AND issuetype = Alert AND status = Submitted AND reporter in (anonymous)") % jira_prj
```

the `% jira_prj` should come before the parenthesis closes -

```
search_alert_issues = jira.search_issues("project = %s AND issuetype = Alert AND status = Submitted AND reporter in (anonymous)" % jira_prj)
```

Right now, you are sending `project = %s AND issuetype = Alert AND status = Submitted AND reporter in (anonymous)` to the server, and then formatting the result with the value in `jira_prj`. When the Jira server sees the %, it complains.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I really appreciate it! Working fine now. A small mistake can definitely ruin a whole script.

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could help. If this answered your question, can you please mark it as accepted? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`% jura_prj` is in wrong position

```
search_alert_issues = jira.search_issues("project = %s AND issuetype = Alert AND status = Submitted AND reporter in (anonymous)" % jira_prj)
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the help, too! :)